# Search for Optimal Point search algorithms

Tags: algorithm, matlab, search, optimization

I have an objective function B(s,r,l), I calculated results for s=1,...,10, r=1,...,10 and l=0.1:0.1:10. for each s, I generated 10 by sizeof(l) matrices. I want to write a search code code such that it will return me minimum B values. In a more clear form

```
Minimize B(s1,r1,l1)+B(s2,r2,l2)+B(s3,r3,l3)

s.t s1+s2+s3 = 10

r1 +r2 +r3 = 15

l1+l2+l3 = 30

s1,s2,s3,r1,r2,r3,l1,l2,l3 >=0
s and r are integer.
```

What is the best search algorithm for the above problem?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to make l3,r3,s3 dependent on the choice of another variables. For example, if *l1 = 1* and *l2 = 2* it implies that *l3 = 30 - 1 - 2*. So you have only 6 parameters left to search for.
Then you should use some kind of non-linear optimization method, like **fminsearh**. Define you functional as a function of these 6 parameters.
If your function is smooth, the integer solution should be near the real solution.

In order to treat the non-zero condition, you can simply give a huge error to any input that gives negative output.

So, your functional should be something like:

```
function d = f(l1,l2,s1,s2,r1,r2)
      l3 = 30 - l1 - l2;
      r3 = 15 - r1 - r2;
      s3 = 10 - s1 - s2;
      z = B(s1,r1,l1)+B(s2,r2,l2)+B(s3,r3,l3);
      if z<0 
          d = 10^20;
      else
          d = z;
      end
end
```

In the end, try to check all of the integer solutions - try to round each value to **floor** or **ceil**.  There will be 2^6 possibilities.

Comment: this is an inspiring comment. I was working on a similar code. Basically I generated my "B" for various combinations of s,r,l. Then I am searching in these matrices. Still way to go. But thanks for the comment

Comment: @sosruko, welcome to SO. There is no need to thank, Accept  instead if the comment is helpful.